# Mongoid each + set vs Critera#set vs update_all + $addToSet

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I was wondering what is better performance / memory wise: Iterating over all objects in a collection and calling set/add_to_set or calling set/add_to_set directly on the Criteria or using update all with set/add_to_set.

```
# update_all
User.where(some_query).update_all(
  {
    '$addToSet': {
      :'some.field.value' => :value_to_add
    }
  }
)

# each do + add_to_set
User.where(some_query).each do |user|
  user.add_to_set(:'some.field.value' => :value_to_add)
end

# Criteria#add_to_set
User.where(some_query).add_to_set(
  :'some.field.value' => :value_to_add
)
```

Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started MongoDB server with verbose flag. That's what I got.

Option 1. update_all applied on a selector

```
2017-04-25 COMMAND command production_v3.$cmd command: update { update: "products", updates: [ { q: { ... }, u: { $addToSet: { test_field: "value_to_add" } }, multi: true, upsert: false } ], ordered: true }
```

I removed some output so that is easier to read. The flow is:

- MongoID generates a single command with query and update specified.
- MongoDB server gets the command. It goes through collection and updates each match in [vague] one go.

Note! You may learn from the source code or take as granted. Since MongoID, as per my terminology, generates command to send in step 1, it does not check your models. e.g. If 'some.field.value' is not one of your field in the model User, then the command will still go through and persist on DB.

Option 2. each on a selector

I get find commands like below followed by multiple getMore-s:

```
2017-04-25 COMMAND command production_v3.products command: find { find: "products", filter: { ... } } 0ms
```

I also get a huge number of update-s:

```
2017-04-25 COMMAND command production_v3.$cmd command: update { update: "products", updates: [ { q: { _id: ObjectId('52a6db196c3f4f422500f255') }, u: { $addToSet: { test_field: { $each: [ "value_to_add" ] } } }, multi: false, upsert: false } ], ordered: true } 0ms
```

The flow is radically different from the 1st option:

- MongoID sends a simple query to to MongoDB server. Provided your collection is large enough and the query covers a material chunk of it, the following happens in a loop:
- [loop] Respond with a subset of all matches. Leave the rest for the next iteration.
- [loop] MongoID gets an array of matching items in Hash format. MongoID parses the each entry and initializes User class for it. That's an expensive operatation!
- [loop] For each User instance from the previous step MongoID generates an update commands and sends it to serve. Sockets are expensive too.
- [loop] MongoDB gets the command and goes through the collection until the first match. Updates the match. It is quick, but adds up once in a loop.
- [loop] MongoID parses the response and updates its User instance accordingly. Expensive and unnecessary.

Option 3. add_to_set applied on a selector

Under the hood it is equivalent to Option 1. Its CPU and Memory overhead is immaterial for the sake of the question.

Conclusion.

Option 2 is so much slower that there is no point in benchmarking. In the particular case I tries, it resulted in 1000s of request to MongoDB and 1000s of User class initialization. Options 1 and 3 resulted in a single request to MongoDB and relied on MongoDB highly optimized engine.